# Solving Integral -syntax or interpretation problems

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, wolfram-alpha-queries

WA interpreter achievement not well this entry from Mathematica, steps need to see the full resolution

input WA

```
   WolframAlpha[" Integrate[1/((1+x^4)*Sqrt[Sqrt[1+x^4]-x^2]),x] "]
```

output WA 
        WA doesn't know how to interpret your input

Mathematica Output
  ArcCot[Sqrt[-x^2 + Sqrt[1 + x^4]]/x]+C

Comment: You may use [**Rubi**](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) for that

Comment: Dear Juan, to be clear, is your question about Wolfram Alpha, rather than Mathematica? If yes, the question is out of scope for the site and we will have to close it.

Comment: This is a question of mathematics and its interaction with Wolfram Alpha,
The expression to integrate works well while not put a root within another root. Days ago I'm in this for at least trying, as it runs through my hands.

Comment: errata "of mathematics " --> "of MATHEMATICA"